# Constructing a naive recession forecast

Tags: r, forecasting, econometrics, macroeconomics

I am testing a variety of models to produce 1-month ahead predictions of [US Recessions](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/USREC).  To benchmark these models, I want to build a naive recession model.  My first thought was to use the current state of the recession variable to predict the next state of the recession variable:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('USREC',src='FRED') 
library(caret)
confusionMatrix(Lag(USREC),USREC,positive = '1')
```

As you can see, this forecast is very accurate.  However, recessions tend to be back-dated so the naive model occasionally has information from the future: it knows a recession has started before the NBER has made an official announcement!

One idea I had was to build a simple glm model relating GDP to recessions.  This method still uses future information (and the quarterly numbers have to be interpolated to monthly ones):

```
#Load Data
getSymbols('GDPC1',src='FRED') 
GDPC1 <- diff(log(GDPC1))
Data <- cbind(USREC,GDPC1)

#Fill NA's in GDP
Data$GDPC1 <- ifelse(is.na(Data$GDPC1),Lag(Data$GDPC1,1),Data$GDPC1)
Data$GDPC1 <- ifelse(is.na(Data$GDPC1),Lag(Data$GDPC1,1),Data$GDPC1)
Data <- na.omit(Data)

#Build Model
model <- glm(USREC~GDPC1,family=binomial(link = "logit"),Data)
forecast <- predict(model,Data)
confusionMatrix(ifelse(forecast>.5,1,0),Data$USREC,positive = '1')
```

On the other hand, this model is a little less accurate, and may be useful as a benchmark, despite it's use of some future information

Are there any other simple recession models I could use as benchmarks?

Comment: http://www.businessinsider.com/the-real-reason-for-the-recession-2009-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided the best way to do this is to use the [recession announcement dates](http://www.nber.org/cycles.html) to construct a `recession` variable that reflects what was known at the time.  [A commentator on my blog](http://moderntoolmaking.blogspot.com/2011/09/recession-forecasting-iii-better-naive.html) was kind enough to go back and construct the data series, which is available as an [excel file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7428423/Modified%20NBER%20Recession%20Data.xls) and as a [csv file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7428423/Modified%20NBER%20Recession%20Data.csv).

Answer (score 1):

Use a logistic model predicting the probability of a recession using independent variables such as the slope of the yield curve, trailing stock market returns, short-interest rate, and credit spreads.

Comment: That's what I did in my example.  `model <- glm(USREC~GDPC1,family=binomial(link = "logit"),Data)`.  I'll add the yield curve, stock market returns, interest rates, and credit spreads as variables

Comment: There is a well-known economic factor model called the BIRR model : www.birr.com/BIRR_Risk_Model.pdf . They are not forecasting recession (they focus on the equity risk premia) however you might find their approach instructive. Several of the variables I suggested are from that model.